# My 64gig SD card thinks its 32gig

Tags: linux, sd-card, ubuntu-18.04, arm, dev

so I cloned my 32-gig emmc into my 64-gig SD card with the "dd" command. The only problem is that it thinks it has 32 gigs of total storage... Does anyone know how to "convince" (actually resize the whole disk to its full capacity) it into having 64 gigs in total? I'm using it on my TX2 dev kit and it boots out of the SD card I copied.

(PSA: the TX2 itself says its 32 gigs and the disk manager confirms it aswell, however, other devices when i plug in the SD card says it has "Total Capacity: 29,5GB, 25,7 used". I'm completely lost)

[image: gparted]
[image: gparted]
[image: gparted]

Comment: "29,5GB, 25,7 used" means it also only sees 32 GB and not 64 GB

Comment: thats exactly the problem, the partition inside 64gig sd card has 64gigs of space, however partition thinks it has 32 gigs...

Comment: I was commenting on what you said that the TX2 says 32 "however" other devices say "29,5GB, 25,7 used", which seemed to me like your saying that those two aren't the same info.

Comment: Try checking the disk with `gparted`

Comment: If you view the disk in something like `gparted` do you see the remaining space?

Comment: Yes thank you, but now I can't click on "check" to allocate unallocated space. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: In Gparted, i see /dev/mmcblk2p1 as 59gb  and when i click on it, it says 53% unallocated. When i click on the unallocated under the partitions, it says 1 Mib of unallocated partition.

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of how it shows in `gparted` and what options you have there

Comment: i have added the pictures, can you check again please

Comment: So it tells you to use the **Check**. When you select the partition (on top) and do Partition->Check what do you get?

Comment: I can't check. the check option is not available.

Comment: I think that's because it's mounted/active (see the key icon on it.) Try selecting the partition and do Partition->Unmount. Then try Check

Comment: @YisroelTech , you are a d@mn legend. I'm so happy that it got fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the partition is not enough. You need to grow the filesystem, too. Whatever you used to clone and/or resize the partition afterwards did not do this. The colors in GParted show this as well.

The solution for *ext4* is super simple. Just do `sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk2p1`, done. You can even do it while the filesystem is mounted read-write. This command will extend the filesystem to fill the entire block device (partition, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

To correct it you need to use a more powerful Disk/Partition manager. `gparted` is typically the go-to application for this.

In `gparted` you will:

- First Unmount the partition (if it is mounted) using **Partition** --> **Unmount**, and then
- Then select the partition and do **Partition** --> **Check** to fix it